# Data on interest rate differentials (lending on own vs. foreign currency)

Tags: interest-rates, data, fx

I'm looking for data on (inner country) interest rate differentials between lending in own and foreign currency. Is there any data publicly available? If yes, where? If not, which non-free sources are available?

Comment: I don't know. I wonder if bis.org would have this data.

Comment: I've already looked there, nothing found.

Comment: The IMFs International Financial Statistics has the data I was looking for!